# Can you use C# Kubernetes inClusterConfig for a remote Cluster?

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am having trouble authenticating my C# service for a remote cluster. Trying to use my svc gets Forbidden, so I am hoping to work around with this. I know that inClusterConfig does work properly when this service is in the Cluster, but I am trying to run local and host jobs in my remote cluster.

This is what I am trying:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST", "Value1");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT", "Value1");

KubernetesClientConfiguration config = new KubernetesClientConfiguration();
config.Host = "https://xx";
            
config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig();
```

Not sure if this is possible. Currently getting error

> Unable to load in-cluster configuration, KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT must be defined

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the environment variables, [`KubernetesClientConfiguration.IsInCluster`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/bdcfbfacf2793a570f6c46a98f4c26d60a1fc4c8/src/KubernetesClient/KubernetesClientConfiguration.InCluster.cs#L22) also requires a token and certificate:

```
if (!FileUtils.FileSystem().File.Exists(tokenPath))
{
 return false;
}

// ...
return FileUtils.FileSystem().File.Exists(certPath);
```

The details of authentication are explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66093610):

> When [accessing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api-1) the API from a Pod, the client certificate is located
> on `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` and in
> addition, you need to authenticate using the token located on
> `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`

Once a connection is being attempted, [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63232640):

> `InClusterConfig` uses the `default` service account of the namespace
> where you are deploying the pod. By default that service account will
> not have any [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) which leads to `Forbidden` error.